# SSL on Elastic Beanstalk with multiple instances (EC2)

Tags: ssl, nginx, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to add Server Certificate to EC2 instances (with NGINX) running in Elastic Beanstalk. And I have a some doubts if it is possible...

**My motivation:** 
I want to validate Client Certificates via NGINX on EC2 instances, which are running behind the Elastic Load Balancer. Client Certificate comes from AWS API Gateway and I  want to use verification to restrict access to my Elastic Beanstalk (EB).

As I've tested (however I might be wrong here), NGINX needs to have Server Certificate to validate Client Certificate:

```
listen 443 ssl;

ssl_certificate xxx;
ssl_certificate_key xxx;

ssl_client_certificate yyy;
ssl_verify_client on;
```

**Questions**

1. Is the server certificate generated for specific domain, subdomain or wildcard subdomains?
2. Is it possible to use the same server certificate on many instances with private IPs behind Load Balancer? (They are not directly bind to domain)
3. Or maybe is it possible to verify client certificate without SSL on nginx? like in the following NGINX config snippet:

   listen 443;

   ssl_client_certificate yyy;
   ssl_verify_client on;